# php mysql join exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application, very basic description:

1. Users login -> they post "activities" (like snowboarding)
2. Users have friends
3. Users can bind multiple friends to activities
4. Users can "like" activities created by friends

What I need is a query to check if the user is allowed to "like" an activity by one of their friends. They are only allowed when one of the users friends was bound to the target activity.

```
users: id, name
usersFriends: id, uid, friendUid
activities: id, description
activitiesUsers: id, activityId, uid
activitiesLikes: id, activityId, uid
```

I hope someone can help me with this query, and if possible to return true or false. I hope my question is clear and thanks for your time :)

Comment: There are three different users/friends in your story. Please label them A, B and C for example, because this is open for multiple interpretations.

Comment: I would *STILL* cleanup your variables and call them by unique names so there is less confusion later so id becomes `userid`, or `friendid`, or `activityid`, etc; This not only makes it clean, it clarifies implied relationships for later JOINS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce a list of `activities.id` for all of the user's friends.

```
SELECT 
  activities.id AS canLikeId
FROM 
  users u
  JOIN usersFriends uf ON u.id = uf.uid
  JOIN activitiesUsers au ON uf.friendId = au.uid
  JOIN activities a ON a.id = au.activityId
```

Wrapped in an `EXISTS`, it looks like:

```
SELECT activities.id FROM activities aCanLike
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      a.id AS canLikeId
    FROM 
      users u
      JOIN usersFriends uf ON u.id = uf.uid
      JOIN activitiesUsers au ON uf.friendId = au.uid
      JOIN activities a ON a.id = au.activityId
    WHERE a.id = aCanLike.id
)
```

Or something with an `IN()` clause that attempts to get everything from `activities` owned by any of the user's friends.

```
SELECT
  activities.*
FROM activities JOIN activitiesUsers ON activities.id = activitiesUsers.activityId
WHERE activitiesUsers.uid IN (
  SELECT friendUid FROM usersFriends WHERE uid = $userid
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the user's id and activity id at the time of the query, you could do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activitiesUsers WHERE activityId = 'xx' AND uid IN (SELECT friendUid FROM usersFriends WHERE uid = 'xx')
```

Should return 0 if none of their friends are bound to the activity or a positive number if they have friends bound to that activity ...

Comment: In some situations I like subselects, and this is one. This query should work. See this article on join vs subselects. http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/7/31/MySQL-performance-INNER-JOIN-vs-subselect

Comment: @mozillanerd: the article you linked shows that the subselect alternative is terribly slower than the join one.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select
    count(*) as CanLike -- 0 if false, >= 1 if true
from
    usersFriends uf
join
    activitiesUsers au
on
    uf.friendUid = au.uid
where 
    au.id = $activityId
and
    uf.uid = $userId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS allowed
FROM userFriends
JOIN activitiesUsers ON (userFriends.uid = activitiesUsers.uid
    AND activitiesUsers.activityId = $activity_id)
WHERE userFriends.uid = $user_id
```